# How to access user's Google drive account from a Service Account?

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, google-authentication, service-accounts

I am working on a Web API and want to allow a user to upload a file from his Google Drive account, which I would fetch from the Service Account associated with my .NET web application.

So far I have succesfully configured a Service Account and am able to create a DriveService instance using its credentials, but I don't know what to do next to access an user drive account, I don't even know what information I need from him and have not found any good documentation on how to achieve that.

```
string[] scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };
                ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("myAppServiceAccountEmail") { Scopes = scopes }.FromPrivateKey(privateKey));

                // Create Drive API service.
                driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "MyApp"
                });
```

Any insight?

Comment: To impersonate users using service account, follow the Service Account guide from the official docs where you will [Delegate domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts#delegatingauthority) to the service account. Additonal [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143095/login-required-401-using-google-serviceaccountcredential-using-google-admin-dire?noredirect=1#comment87376153_50143095)

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot. So from what I understand, a user can upload a file and somehow authorize my Service Account to access the file but how the user would achieve that?