# How to authorize a Service Account to access a user Drive Account?

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I am trying to allow a user to share files with my web application, my application has a Service Account and it has succesfuly been configured using G Suite.

However I am not able to authenticate a user, say johndoe@gmail.com on the ServiceAccount to access his uploaded files, using the following code:

```
ServiceAccountCredential serviceAccountCredential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("service_account_secret.json").CreateScoped(DriveServiceScope).CreateWithUser("john_doe@gmail.com").UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
```

I get the following exception when making a request with the DriveService:

> Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException:
>   'Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Client is unauthorized to
>   retrieve access tokens using this method.", Uri:""'

**What does johndoe@gmail.com needs to do in order to authorize my ServiceAccount to access his files?**

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143095

Answer (score 0):

When you created your service account on Google Developer console you picked the wrong type.  The code and credentials files are different for the different types of credentials.

You probably created browser or native app credentials

Here is some spample code for .net as well

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Authenticating to Google using a Service account
    /// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceAccountEmail">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
    /// <param name="serviceAccountCredentialFilePath">Location of the .p12 or Json Service account key file downloaded from Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
    /// <returns>AnalyticsService used to make requests against the Analytics API</returns>
    public static DriveService AuthenticateServiceAccount(string serviceAccountEmail, string serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, string[] scopes)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                throw new Exception("Path to the service account credentials file is required.");
            if (!File.Exists(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                throw new Exception("The service account credentials file does not exist at: " + serviceAccountCredentialFilePath);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountEmail))
                throw new Exception("ServiceAccountEmail is required.");                

            // For Json file
            if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".json")
            {
                GoogleCredential credential;
                using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                         .CreateScoped(scopes);
                }

                // Create the  Analytics service.
                return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Drive Service account Authentication Sample",
                });
            }
            else if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".p12")
            {   // If its a P12 file

                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = scopes
                }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                // Create the  Drive service.
                return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Drive Authentication Sample",
                });
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Unsupported Service accounts credentials.");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw new Exception("CreateServiceAccountDriveFailed", ex);
        }
    }
}
}
```

code ripped from [serviceaccount.cs](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/ServiceAccount.cs)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the account is indeed a Service Account and the credentials file that I use is correct. However what I try to do, is to connect a given user "johndoe@gmail.com" for example to access his own files through my ServiceAccout, and I can't find how to do that?

Comment: take the service account email address and have him share a folder with it like you would share with any other user.